# Drawing a star on a sphere

Tags: graphics

I am trying to draw a star on a sphere. To determine the points belonging to the star I need to count the number of halfspaces that the points on the sphere belong to out of the 5 halfspaces defined by alternating points of the regular pentagon drawn on the x-y plane. My problem is determining the equations of those planes. I know 2 points, 2 alternating points of hexagons: (v0, v2), (v0, v3), (v1, v3), (v1, v4), (v2, v4). Assuming all planes are parallel to the z-axis, it seems to me intuitively this is enough info to find the plane equation, but my math is a little rusty and cannot do it. Appreciate any leads of how to calculate the equations or pointing out the flaw in my assumption...

Comment: Well I figured that if we take the cross product of the vector joining the 2 known points and the z-axis (the vector parallel to the plane), we get the normal of the plane up to a sign, then it is easy to derive the plane equation from the normal and a point. However, I still have a question of how to set up the calculations so that all planes have the same sense of inside...

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to draw a star an a sphere, it will probably look better if the arcs are geodesics.  That makes it easier for you, since the planes that define those arcs (by intersecting the sphere) will then all pass through the sphere's center.

Finding those planes is easy, too.  You just take the cross product of the vectors from the center to any two points to find the normal.  If the sphere's center is at (0,0,0), you don't need anything else.

Comment: Thanks, so I draw the equator and locate the points of the pentagon that are on it, basically the same points on the x-y plane, then draw the longitude lines that pass through every pair of non-adjacent points. Then the intersections of these longitude lines on the sphere give me the points defining the star at the north/south poles. Did I get that right? I need to be sure before embarking into the computation with rusty math

Comment: Ah, no.  The method I outline doesn't work if the points go all the way out to the equator, since all the planes would end up the same.  If you need it that big, then some other method will be better.

Comment: But if the points are in the x-y plane then the normal vector is the z-axis; same as my first attempt.

Comment: Well, if we get the slope of each line joining 2 non-consecutive points, then get the slope of the line perpendicular to it, i.e.  [v2y - v1y , v1x - v2x, 0] we have the normals of all our 5 planes. Then we can choose the 4th component of the plane equation = to any value we choose according to how big we want our star to be...